# Failed to update id

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have created a crud application with nodejs and sequelize, but when i try to update a recored via postman it return me with 0 value, kindly any help

```
my code are here below
const userDB = require('../models/index');
exports.update=(req, res) =>{
 if(!req.body){
  return res.status(400).send({
   message:"Data to update can not be empty"
  });
 }
const id =req.params.id;
userDB.User.update(id,{
   where:{
      id:id
   }
}).then((data)=>{
   if(!data){
      res.status(400).send({message:`Cannot update user with ID ${id}, user might not exist`})
   }else{
      res.send(data)
   }
}).catch(err=>{
   res.status(500).send({
      message:"Error update user information"
   })
})
 
}
```

Comment: could you please log what is data value

Comment: this is the return request from postman
[
    0
]

Comment: I new type of it in backend

Comment: Guys any help to my question

Comment: what do you want to update ? Your code `.update(id,{where:{id:id}}).` doesn't update anything ?